# The `vendored_frameworks` pattern did not match any file

Tags: realm

While adding Realm for Objective C in Vendored framework in my custom podspec file it gives me an error

```
- ERROR | [iOS] file patterns: The `vendored_frameworks` pattern did not match any file.
```

In my podspec file I have entry:

```
s.vendored_frameworks = "Realm.framework"
```

Error came when I run command `pod spec lint`

Comment: Could you make sure that `Realm.framework` located current directory?

Comment: I have added in Realm.framework in framework section, do I need to copy in Project directory? Can you suggest steps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CocoaPods doesn't respect project settings at all. It just refers to a Podspec file. You put `Realm.framework` same directory as podspec. If you write `s.vendored_frameworks = "Realm.framework"`, the path will be resolved related to the current directory.

Comment: I did this and still does not work for me i keep seeing : ERROR | [iOS] file patterns: The `vendored_frameworks` pattern did not match any file. any idea why, my .framework file is in the same place where the podspec file is and my pod spec is : s.vendored_frameworks = 'Foo.framework'

Comment: @Max did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 4):

Try doing `pod cache clean --all`
This worked after I tagged a new version and pushed it up.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to your project Releases in GitHub.
2. Download Source code (zip).
3. See if "Realm.framework" is inside the folder.

[image]